# deploying on Wildfly with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a .war on locally installed Wildfly (JBoss 8 Beta1). It works fine with console and maven commands, but fails miserably in Intellij Idea 12:

```
[2013-10-28 11:11:16,587] Artifact sample:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 9999
Detected server http port: 8080
```

Any hints how to deploy a package using Idea IDE ?

```
% java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Comment: problem solved: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5502042#5502042. briefly, JDK that IDE bases on should be exactly the same as the one that Wildfly uses.

Comment: Thanks! To change the JRE used by IntelliJ please refer to: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40319369/597657