# WildFly 8.1: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

I'm running WildFly 8.1 in IntelliJ 14. The server starts and is accessible at `localhost:8080`. The artefact is deployed and the web site can be opened.

BUT

As soon as I *redeploy*, I get:

> Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Nothing is written to server.log

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your IP in stanalone.xml set to **127.0.0.1** :).

This one works:).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem:

You need to run exactly the same jdk on Wildfly and IntelliJ. Since I use MacOS and used the apple 1.6 jdk for IntelliJ and Oracle JDK 7 development and Wildfly, so it didn't work. I switched my IntelliJ to Oracle JDK 7 and now it's deploying and running.

The same problem is described here:
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5502042#5502042

And here's a knowledge base entry on how to switch the JDK IntelliJ is runnung under:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: It doesn't have to be exact. I switch between 1.7 and 1.8 all day for different projects without changing my IntelliJ version. I used to explicitly set IntelliJ to 1.7, but now I just use whatever they are defaulting to.

Answer (score 0):

Check if management interface of wildfly is bound to localhost/127.0.0.1 as well

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when trying to deploy to Wildfly (Idea 14.1, Wildfly 9.0.0 Final), but ensuring the same JDK didn't solve it.  In my case, the issue was in Wildfly's standalone.xml configuration.

Under `<management-interfaces>`, I had to add the following:

```
<native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
    <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
</native-interface>
```

Also, in the `<socket-binding-group>` section, I had to add the following:

```
<socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9990}"/>
```

After making the above changes, deployment worked fine, even with mismatched Idea/Wildfly JDK versions.

Note too that in my case, initial deployment gave the same error ("Server not connected..."), which makes sense if that socket binding wasn't configured.

Answer (score 0):

Same error is comming if (in IDEA) your wildfly user/password is wrong. To change the user/password in IDEA open the "Application Servers" view, edit the configuration of your WildFly server and check the username and password in the "Server" tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running standalone-full.xml rather than the default standalone.xml, then pass this environment variable:

```
-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml
```

[image]

instead of passing arguments at the startup script:

```
...\standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml
```

---

If you are running standalone-full.xml rather than the default standalone.xml, then just delete standalone.xml and rename standalone-full.xml to standalone.xml.This solved the following problem for me :)

> Server is not connected. Deploy is not available